# How to find the correct url

Tags: vba, url, xmlhttprequest

I use vba/xmlhttp to retrieve history data of daily quotes of Taiwan Stock Exchange Corp..  Recently the web page I used to scrape data changed, the url shown in IE remained the same when I clicked query button.  I cannot get the exact url anymore.

I tried the Developer's Tool of IE to find the url but failed.
In the Network tab of developer's tool, the url accessed can be recorded.  From the recorded detail I know the url is "http://www.twse.com.tw/ch/trading/exchange/MI_INDEX/MI_INDEX.php" (same as shown in the url bar of IE), and the request body is "download=&qdate=104%2F01%2F05&selectType=ALLBUT0999"(in this example, Taiwan year=104, month=01, day=05).  According to my personal experience, the url should be "http://www.twse.com.tw/ch/trading/exchange/MI_INDEX/MI_INDEX.php?download=&qdate=104%2F01%2F05&selectType=ALLBUT0999".  But this time it failed.

Is there any tool I can use to find the correct url?

Comment: If the query parameters are in the request body, then the page is doing a POST request, not a GET (for a Get the parameters would be in the URL itself). The two request types aren't necessarily interchangeable - depends on how the sever-side part is coded.

Answer (score 0):

If the site is correct, try a **tracert** in cmd (I assume you use windows). Then, try each IP address for the correct one.

Tracert just fetches each IP accessed in the process of accessing one IP.

The syntax is: `tracert http://www.twse.com.tw/ch/trading/exchange/MI_INDEX/MI_INDEX.php`.

Comment: I do use Windows, but not familiar with the console command.  I tried "tracert http://www.twse.com.tw/ch/..."(with http://) and "tracert www.twse.com.tw/ch/...". Both get the message "can not resolve target name".  "tracert www.twse.com.tw" execute correctly, but just 4 addresses reported, the other 26 hops are timeout.  The reported addresses have nothing to do with www.twse.com.tw.  Anyway thanks for your reply.